# how to return the ID of a resource which was created by ajax HTTP POST to the client

Tags: jquery, ajax, http, rest

I'm wondering whether there is a standardized way to get the identity (id/hash/whatever) of the object/resource which was just created on the server via POST. Is there some HTTP header which can be set?

I'm using jquery right now, and what I do is to output the id of the created object into a hidden html div. After getting the response on the client, I parse the html, and retrieve the id. That seems kind of awkward to me. Any ideas?

Comment: Try to respond with JSON and then parse the JSON on the client side.

Comment: Can you provide us with a snippet of your javascript request? Would be nice to see what you're doing, because it is definately awkward :)

Comment: think of a scenario where you want to submit some data to the server via $('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container',{ title: 'myNewObj' });
how do i get the ID of the newly created object here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Location header is designed specifically for this purpose.   When you create a resource, the origin server should return 201 and the Location header should contain the URL to the newly created resource.

See: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could return a JSON list object, with an `id` key pointing to an `id` value, and a `rawHTML` key that contains the raw HTML that you want to pour into the div. Then you parse the JSON response for the keys' values.

Comment: yeah, thats a way of doing it. but you cant use cool jquery functionality like $('#mydiv').load(...) with it.